# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralName.getDERObject()

Tags: java, itext, x509certificate, bouncycastle, nosuchmethoderror

I have done migrating project from **itext2.1.7.jar** to **itext5.5.13.jar** but While testing the pdf which are having signatures am getting the below error:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralName.getDERObject()**

This is the method where I am getting error:

```
   public URI getCrlUri(X509Certificate certificate) {

              byte[] crlDistributionPointsValue = certificate.getExtensionValue(Extension.cRLDistributionPoints.getId());

              if (null == crlDistributionPointsValue) {

                     return null;

              }

              CRLDistPoint distPoint=null;

              try {

                     distPoint = CRLDistPoint

.getInstance(JcaX509ExtensionUtils.parseExtensionValue(crlDistributionPointsValue));

              } catch (IOException e) {

                                          e.printStackTrace();

              }

              DistributionPoint[] distributionPoints = distPoint.getDistributionPoints();

              for (DistributionPoint distributionPoint : distributionPoints) {

                     DistributionPointName distributionPointName = distributionPoint.getDistributionPoint();

                     if (DistributionPointName.FULL_NAME != distributionPointName.getType()) {

                           continue;

                     }

                     GeneralNames generalNames = (GeneralNames) distributionPointName.getName();

                     GeneralName[] names = generalNames.getNames();

                     for (GeneralName name : names) {

                           if (name.getTagNo() != GeneralName.uniformResourceIdentifier) {

                                  continue;

                           }

                    

                            final DERIA5String derStr = DERIA5String.getInstance(name.getDERObject());

                      

 

                           String str = derStr.getString();

                           URI uri = toURI(str);

                           return uri;

                     }

              }

              return null;

       }
```

In my class path I have placed:
**1.bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar**
**2.bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar**
**3.itextpdf-5.5.13.jar**

BouncyCastle libs I have added according the pom.xml which I got while downloading itextpdf.

This project was built on following bouncy castle libs
**1.bcmail-jdk16-143.jar**
**2.bcprov-jdk16-143.jar**
**3.bctsp-jdk16-1.44.jar**

Can anyone please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update a dependency of your code (here: iText) and transitive dependencies along with it (here: BouncyCastle), and you use those transitive dependencies in your own code, too, then you must be prepared to also adapt your code to the changes in the transitive dependencies.

In this case you use `GeneralName.getDERObject()`:

```java
final DERIA5String derStr = DERIA5String.getInstance(name.getDERObject());
```

That method was present in earlier BouncyCastle versions, in particular the 1.30s. In the course of the 1.40s this method was replaced by `getEncoded()` or `getEncoded("DER")`. Thus, try something like:

```java
final DERIA5String derStr = DERIA5String.getInstance(name.getEncoded("DER"));
```

Beware, though, in those days the BouncyCastle API was very volatile, you might have to adapt more of your code using BouncyCastle...

---

In a comment you mention

> now I'm getting :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: encoding error in getInstance: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERTaggedObject cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERIA5String

Please try

```java
final DERIA5String derStr = DERIA5String.getInstance(name.getName());
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @mkl. I have added the code and NoSuchMethodError issue got fixed but now I'm getting :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: encoding error in getInstance: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERTaggedObject cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERIA5String

Comment: I tried name.getName(), name.toASN1Object(), name.toDERObject() getting NoSuchMethodError() in all of them. Please Help.

Comment: thanks alot @mkl . According to our answer, I have updated all my code in project and now it's working.